# awk to combine all lines in file with another

Tags: bash, awk

The below `awk` combines the target.txt with the out_parse.txt and the output is GJ-53.txt. If there are multiple lines in out_parse how can they both be written to GJ-53.txt? As of now  the first line of `out_parse` saves to a text file `GJ-53`, but the second line does not.  Than you :).

```
awk '{close(fname)} (getline fname<f)>0 {print>fname}' f=target.txt out_parse.txt
```

**Contents of out_parse.txt**

```
13  20763612    20763612    C   T
13  20763620    20763620    A   G
```

**Contents of target.txt**

```
GJ-53.txt

 cat -v out_parse.txt
 13      20763612        20763612        C       T
 13      20763620        20763620        A       G
```

Comment: Please show how I would like to see final file (GJ-53.txt). Same as out_parse.txt? Is there any reason to use `awk` instead just copy? `cp out_parse.txt $(head -1 target.txt)`

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do (not HOW you are trying to do it) as the script as written makes no sense so it's hard for us to help you as we can't tell what it is you actually want the script to do. Also, before we go any further, run `cat -v` on your files to see if they contain any control-Ms and if so remove those with `dos2unix` or similar.

Comment: Regarding your script: lines in  out_parse.txt should printed `{print>fname}` if `getline` will receive data with some numbers `(getline fname<f)>0` but there is 1 line in `target.txt` only. So when script operate second line the `getline` receive nothing, so just fist line will be printed

Comment: I figured it out thanks to the suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to copy the contents of `out_parse.txt` to a new file, whose name is given in the file `target.txt`. To do that, you don't really need to use awk at all:

```
cp out_parse.txt "$(< target.txt)"
```

In bash, `$(< file)` can be use as a substitution for the contents of `file`. It achieves the same thing as `$(cat file)`.

If you wanted to use awk, you could do something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f=$0;next}{print>f}' target.txt out_parse.txt
```

The first block applies to the first file, where the total record number `NR` is equal to the current file's record number `FNR`. It saves the content of the line (i.e. the filename) to `f` and skips any further instructions. The second block applies only to the second file and prints every line to the filename saved in `f`.